# TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: Only size 1 arrays are accepted

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently stuck on an error regarding my neural network. The dataset consists of a 2418 arrays with each containing 400 numbers. The shape is (2418,400). After trial and error I reshaped this to (2418,400,1) because I thought that would be better for the model. The error I receive when running is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-370efbb6619c>", line 9, in <module>
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(Xreshaped), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpointable\base.py", line 442, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 160, in add
    name=layer.name + '_input')

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 231, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 107, in __init__
    name=self.name)

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 876, in placeholder
    x = array_ops.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 2077, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 5788, in placeholder
    shape = _execute.make_shape(shape, "shape")

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 147, in make_shape
    raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))

TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
```

I've looked at a similar post on Stackoverflow but the answer didn't work out for this case. My code looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(Xreshaped), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)

# mean_squared_error = mse
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=3, validation_data=(X, Y))
```

Comment: What is the value of Xreshaped? Is it shape value of reshaped X? if reshaped X shouldn't you be using Xreshaped.shape ?

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a value error now. The shape it receives is [None, 2418, 400, 1], but it expects ndim=3 instead of 4. I can't seem to work around because i don't understand the None dimension. I will try and solve this question.

Comment: How do you get Xreshaped? What is the shape of X?

Comment: I fixed the problem. I used X.reshape((2418,400,1)) and used (400,1) as an input_shape!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is fixed with using:

```
Xreshaped = X.reshape((2418,400,1))

input_shape = (400,1)
```